# How do i remove my module using RequireJs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am new to RequireJS and hence I am facing quite a lot of issues.I am creating an application which involves 3 levels(Easy,Medium,Hard).
Each level has a html and a js file associated with it. I would like to load exactly one of the three files(easy.js,medium.js,hard.js) along with another 2 standard js files(which I wish to have loaded all the time).

This is my config file:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "lib",
    paths: {
        activity: "../js"
    }
});

requirejs(["activity/activity","activity/levels"]);
```

I would wish to load exactly one of the easy.js , medium.js or hard.js. So I wish to have,

```
requirejs(["activity/activity","activity/levels","activity/easy"]);
```

or

```
requirejs(["activity/activity","activity/levels","activity/medium"]);
```

or

```
requirejs(["activity/activity","activity/levels","activity/hard"]);
```

One option I could do is to create 3 separate config files(one for each level),but I don't think this is the best option.So,is there any way that I can do this using a single config file?

Answer (score 0):

You could load the dependencies based on the state which can be hold in the variable:

```js
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "lib",
    paths: {
        activity: "../js"
    }
});

requirejs(["activity/activity","activity/levels", "activity" + difficulty]);
```

But this would require to know the `difficulty` at runtime.

Comment: Hey,I am beginner in RequireJS so hence I have a lot of queries. Is it possible to import a variable into a config file just like how we import in normal js files?

Comment: Config file is just a regular javascript file so it works like any js file :)